# PDO query to return numeric array of result

Tags: pdo

I have the following code:

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM t_user");
print_r($result);
```

The result of print_r is an associative array of values.  I want it to be a numeric array of values.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that:

```
$numeric_array = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Should give you the numeric array of values that you're looking for.